# How to create friendlist in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of users with columns (id, usertag, name, email, password)
I want to create a friend list for each user.

Users table:

```
+-----+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| id  |tag       | name      | email    | password   |
+-----+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1   |#1111     | X-user    | x@email  | ****       |
+-----+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 2   |#2222     | Y-user    | y@email  | ****       |
+-----+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 3   |#3333     | Z-user    | z@email  | ****       | 
+-----+----------+-----------+----------+------------+  
| 4   |#4444     | K-user    | x@email  | ****       | 
+-----+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Friends table:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|#1111  |#2222  |#3333  |#4444  | // column for each user
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|#3333  |#3333  |#1111  |#3333  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|#2222  |#1111  |#2222  |#1111  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|#4444  |       |#4444  |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

How can I link both tables and is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Any strict constraint to only stick to relational databases?

Answer (score 1):

If relational databases are the only option, one way I can think is to store the relationships in a separate table (View this as an adjacency list for edges of a node).

```
Relationship

+---------+----------+
| P1      | P2       |
+---------+----------+
| #1111   |#2222     |
+---------+----------+
| #1111   |#3333     |
+---------+----------+
| #2222   |#3333     |
+---------+----------+
| #4444   |#1111     |
+---------+----------+
```

Note: While querying, depending upon whether the relationship is uni-directional or bi-directional, can choose whether to search in one or both columns.

For bi-directional using union may be one solution:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE tag IN
(SELECT P2 as p FROM RELATIONSHIP WHERE P1=#1111 
UNION 
SELECT P1 as p FROM RELATIONSHIP WHERE P2=#1111)
```